# avaya expansion boot loop

Tags: avaya

We have an Avaya IP Office 500 with a DCPx30 (v.6.0.8) expansion. After coming back from a weekend we found the phones to be non-functioning. After looking over the system I found that the Base unit appeared to be working fine but the 30 port expansion box was in some kind of boot loop.

Having seen things like this before I used my trusty serial cable to connect to the expansion box via a terminal emulator. This confirmed that the expansion was in a boot loop. I then ran the AT-X commands to erase the NVRAM on the box. After running the commands the box began TFTP requests to get a new config. After getting the new settings file via TFTP, the box went right back into its boot loop. Realizing that I was running the v7 of the admin tool, I then downloaded the 6.0.8 version of the admin software since that would have the proper config files. The expansion box took the 6.0.8 config file via TFTP and once done it went right into the same boot loop. I am at a loss at this point.

The base device can take calls and the voice-mail system appears to be working. I even tried moving the expansion box to a different port on the back and it displayed the same behaviour.

Does anyone have an idea what else i can try?

Comment: We have a IP500 here delivered by our ISP/telephone supplier.. it randomly crashed, extensions got deleted without reason etc.. got them to replace it. Perhaps you should call Avaya directly?

Comment: Trying to see if we can do some kind of warranty replacement now, hopefully that pans out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone must have been in our server room over the weekend. From the looks of it there was an ethernet cable plugged into the Digital Station. When that was unplugged, the DS rebooted just fine. Now I get to check some server logs to see who was in there.